# An open source library for handling Recurring Events

Tags: c++, c, ruby, recurrence

I want to implement a calendar app and wanted to handle recurring events, as calculation of recurrence is complex I was wondering if any open source libraries are available. I would prefer these libs to be in C/C++.I found some libs using ruby. But I am not sure how to use those in a C++ environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/) which allows you to expand all recurrences in the [iCalendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) proposed standard. Beware: implementing a *serious* calendar app requires a *huge* effort. Unless you are forced to do this, think twice.